# C# web api returns the wrong amount of data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I have a very simple webapi that returns the wrong amount of data, the API is so simple I simply don't see how this can happen, the controller code is below:

```
[HttpGet("{TillID}")]
public IEnumerable<object> Get(int tillID, int StartAtRow=0, int TakeNoOfRows=1000)
{
    string hmCompanyId;
    string languageName;
    PrepareParameter(tillID, out hmCompanyId, out languageName);

    var tillData = from tbd in _context.TillBasicData.OrderBy(i => i.ItemId).Skip(StartAtRow).Take(TakeNoOfRows)
                   where tbd.CompanyId == hmCompanyId && tbd.languageCode == languageName
                   select tbd;

    return tillData.ToList();
}
```

if I use the following URL to call the API I would expect 10 rows of data but I only get 3

```
https://host.domain.zzz:5443/api/till/tilldata/1?StartAtRow=1&TakeNoOfRows=10
```

Similar if I use the following URL I would expect 20 rows but I get 5

```
https://host.domain.zzz:5443/api/till/tilldata/1?StartAtRow=1&TakeNoOfRows=20
```

Manually querying the DB shows the data in the DB is correct.

Why do I not get the correct amount of rows returned?

EDIT, the following SQL code returns 351443 with the same matching where clause as the actual where clause in the controller

```
select count(*) from tillbasicdata where CompanyId = 'BE_HM' and languageCode = 'eng'
```

EDIT, The server log shows the query being executed looks ok, the variables have to be correct because if I increase rows to take to 100 I get more than 10 which should be returned in URL 1

Comment: shown us the query you execute at the db. It probably does not match the query as shown in the code. Did you take a look at the query generated by the code?

Comment: What I mean is that there is 300 000 rows in the DB so the data is there, the problem is that it always returns less than my TakeNoOfRows variable, the where clause doesn't change it just consistently give me about 1/3 to 1/4 of the number in the variable

Comment: You should not "expect 10 rows of data" but rather you would expect to get a *max* of 10 rows of data, if there are enough matches in the where clause.

Comment: @nurdyguy there are 300 000 plus matching rows of data with that where clause, if I just increase the variable to take 100 rows I get 30 which is more than 10 from the first query, the where clause don't change just cause I change the number of rows taken and that should prove there is 10 rows to return in URL invocation 1 now?

Comment: Well, my statement is still true but that is an interesting situation.  Set the debugger and look at the query generated, as Peter suggested above.  Post that query.

Comment: What SQL is being generated in your C# query? (Check what's hitting the database.) That may give you an idea. Does this match the SQL query that you put at the bottom of your question?

Comment: You might want to put where clause before skip and take. `_context.TillBasicData.Where(tbd=>tbd.CompanyId == hmCompanyId && tbd.languageCode == languageName).OrderBy(i => i.ItemId).Skip(StartAtRow).Take(TakeNoOfRows);`

Comment: Use this to output the query that is being generated and run against DB:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectquery.totracestring.aspx

Comment: Debug your code, inspect the list before it is being returned, does it contain the right number of objects?

Comment: Additionally, why are you executing `Skip` and `Take` *before* you filter with your where clause? Are you even sure your query is right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the order in which you have written your query statement. The way you have it now you are ordering the table, taking the top XXX of the ordered table, and then applying the filter to only those records.

Lets say the there are 1 million records and you want 20 that match the filter. In your existing query you take the first 20 in the unfiltered data table and then apply the filter to those top 20, you will be lucky if there are any matches at all.

What you want is to apply the filter to all the data in the table and then take the top XXX of that filtered result.

```
var tillData = _context.TillBasicData
                .Where(tbd => tbd.CompanyId == hmCompanyId && tbd.languageCode == languageName)
                .OrderBy(i => i.ItemId)
                .Skip(StartAtRow)
                .Take(TakeNoOfRows)
                .ToList();
return tillData;
```

Comment: Will this also work if I download in batches? first invocation start at 0 take 10 rows, then start at 10 take 10, start at 20 take 10?

Comment: @MattDouhan - Yes but you must filter first, then sort, then skip, and then take in that order.

Comment: works like a charm, once you explained it it all makes sense, the table has 4 languages for every item, so thats why I would get roughly 25% of the expected rows every time because I was working on the unfiltered list and then filtering which would remove the languages not passing the filter, I was further confused because I compared this to a count api which of course doesn't care about the order at all it just counts the rows passing the filter